# Angular typeahead dynamic positioning

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

Can we make the angular typeahead position itself automatically like select?
If the element is at the bottom of the screen the results should populate up.
Please give an example of this.

Comment: https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv

Answer (score 0):

Check for the html how to present how two way binding using ng-model works.

Link for codepen illustrates the example: https://codepen.io/deep060494/pen/ezBqay

```
<input name="states" id="states" type="text" placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
            </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>

      <div><span>{{selected}}</span></div>
```